# Ajax code run on Local Host xamp but not working on Hosting?

Tags: ajax

**HTML**
I am running below code on localhost xamp. its running well.
when i upload code into hosting its not working (not sending mail)..
my mail file code is ok. I run mail file separate mail file is working. 
when i use my **mail file into ajax** mail file not working..

```
<div class="col-md-6 contact-bottom bottom-frm-div">
    <form action="" method="post" id="cnt-form" class="cnt-form">
        <input type="text" value="First Name" name="name" placeholder="" onfocus="this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'First Name';}">  
        <input type="text" value="Last Name" name="lname" placeholder="" onfocus="this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Last Name';}">               
        <input type="text" value="Email Address" placeholder="" name="email" onfocus="this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email Address';}">
        <textarea placeholder="" name="msg" onfocus="this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Message';}">Message</textarea>    
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit" id="send">
    </form> 
    <div id="loader3" style="display: none;">Success</div>

</div>
```

**Ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function(){
    $('#cnt-form').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this);
            var post_url = 'contact-mail-file.php';
            var post_data = form.serialize();
            $('#loader3', form).html('<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Loading_icon.gif" width="100px" /> Please wait...');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: post_url, 
                data: post_data,
                success: function(msg) {
                    $(form).fadeOut(800, function(){
                        form.html(msg).fadeIn().delay(2000);

                        $('#loader3').show();

                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**PHP Mail file**

```
<? 
if(isset($_POST['send']))
{
$name=$_POST['name'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['msg'];


$to='inderjeetoffice@gmail.com';


$subject = "Enquiry from Inderjeet - ".date('d F Y h:i:s A');
$from = $email;
$message = '<html><body><table border=0 width=554><tr><td colspan=2><p><b>Enquiry from Setyourbiz</b><br><br></p></td></tr><tr><td colspan=2 class=text4>FORM submitted at '.date('d F Y h:i:s A').'<br></td></tr>
<tr><td width=200 class=text3>Name :</td><td class=text3>'.$name.' '.$lname.'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Email Id :</td><td>'.$email.'</td></tr>

<tr><td>Message :</td><td>'.$message.'</td></tr>
</table></body></html>';

mail( $to, $subject, $message, "From:$from\r\nReply-to:$from\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=us-ascii", "-f$to" );

$msg=urlencode("Your enquiry has been submitted successfully.");
echo "<script>alert('Your Query is Submited');</script>";

}?>
```

**Edit**

In hosting: PHP Version 5.4.45

In XAMP: PHP Version 5.6.24

Comment: which php version you are using on local and on hosting server ? Can you check and let me know... i will help you out

Comment: do you get any error , check console

Answer (score 0):

PHP VERSION PLEASE ?

OF LOCAL AND LIVE BOTH ?

CHECK WITH PHPINFO()

Comment: In hosting: PHP Version 5.4.45
In XAMP: PHP Version 5.6.24

Comment: on local or live ?

Comment: tell me both versions